Firebase migrate configuration from 1st gen to 2nd gen
I am trying to migrate some of firebase functions to 2nd gen and currently having issues on how to migrate the configurations.
The issue is there is an index.js file which fetches the configuration using functions.config() which is being used to identify environment I am currently using. I just want to migrate http trigger function to 2nd gen and leave other pubsubs and triggers to 1st gen.
I cannot use functions.config() for the http trigger function for 2nd gen but I would have to use it for the other functions which are currently on 1st gen.
Any idea how can I add the configurations so that it could be used by both 1st gen and 2nd gen functions?
For now, I just tried hardcoding the configs to check if it works or not.
